# Extracting the data from the same position over multiple lines in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fairly simple question but I can't figure out where i'm going wrong. I have a text file which I have split into multiple lines. I want to print a certain location from each line, characters 14 to 20 but when I run the below code it prints a blank set of a characters.

```
with open('filetxt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().rstrip()

for line in data:
    print(line[14:20])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the file line by line, try:

```
with open('filetxt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line[14:20])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong `read()` method. `read()` reads the whole file at once you might want to use `readlines()` which returns a list of the read lines. I.e.:

```py
with open('filetxt', 'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()

  for line in lines:
    print(line[14:20])
```